# Why will ActiveWindow.SplitColumn not work when excel is a COM object?

Tags: excel, vba, office-interop

I have some fairly old technology, Office Web Components (OWC).

This means on my web page I have Excel embedded as an OLE object

```
<object classid="clsid:0002E551-0000-0000-C000-000000000046" id="Spreadsheet1" width="1100" height="750">
            <param name="DataType" value="XMLDATA" />
            <param name="AllowPropertyToolbox" value="-1" />
            <param name="AutoFit" value="1" />
            <param name="Calculation" value="-4105" />
            <param name="Caption" value="Microsoft Office-regneark" />
            <param name="DisplayColumnHeadings" value="-1" />
            <param name="DisplayGridlines" value="-1" />
            <param name="DisplayHorizontalScrollBar" value="-1" />
            <param name="DisplayOfficeLogo" value="-1" />
            <param name="DisplayPropertyToolbox" value="0" />
            <param name="DisplayRowHeadings" value="-1" />
            <param name="DisplayTitleBar" value="0" />
            <param name="DisplayToolbar" value="-1" />
            <param name="DisplayVerticalScrollBar" value="-1" />
            <param name="DisplayWorkbookTabs" value="1" />
            <param name="EnableEvents" value="-1" />
            <param name="MaxHeight" value="80%" />
            <param name="MaxWidth" value="80%" />
            <param name="MoveAfterReturn" value="-1" />
            <param name="MoveAfterReturnDirection" value="-4121" />
            <param name="RightToLeft" value="0" />
            <param name="ScreenUpdating" value="-1" />
            <param name="EnableUndo" value="-1" />
            <!--param name="XMLURL" value="rangeirange.xml"-->
        </object>
```

I guess that is not overly important, but then I want to freeze some columns, and normally I can use all VBA in JavaScript, but this code fails:

```
exlObj = document.all.Spreadsheet1;
exlObj.ActiveWindow.SplitColumn = 3;
```

The exlObj does have the ActiveWindow property, but it doesn't have the SplitColumn property.

### Edit:

Now I have investigated, and here is the code issue. Notice this is JavaScript, but it mimic VBA because thats how COM works ofcourse.

```
        exlObj.Sheets(1).Activate();
        exlObj.ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = false;
        exlObj.Sheets(1).Range('B2').Activate();
        exlObj.ActiveCell.Value = 'Foo';
        //exlObj.ActiveWindow.SplitRow = 10;
        exlObj.ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = true; // <- this is the line
```

My problem is that the FreezePanes property is always false, even after the last line.

What could be the problem with a property acting like this? I have some old code that does aproximatly the same, and works.

Comment: hm weird.. does the [**SplitRow**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837128(v=office.15).aspx) work? how about [**SplitHorizontal**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822891(v=office.15).aspx) and [**SplitVertical**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195965(v=office.15).aspx)??

Comment: Neither SplitRow, SplitHorizonal nor SplitVertical works for ActiveWindow.

Comment: It's hard to research anything on the topic and I am not familiar with OWC anyways so I am sorry I can't help much.

Comment: Sheet1.Range("B2").Activate
   ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
both works. So I think I can use those somehow to do what I want. Unfortunatly they don't act the same way in JavaScript as inside Excel, so I have to work that out.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out I just have to use Select instead of Activate

```
    exlObj.Sheets(1).Activate();
    exlObj.ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = false;
    exlObj.Sheets(1).Range('B2').Select(); <-- changed Activate() to Select()
    exlObj.ActiveCell.Value = 'Foo';
    //exlObj.ActiveWindow.SplitRow = 10;
    exlObj.ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = true; // <- this is the line
```

Comment: Where is Select in the above?

Comment: @QHarr I have no idea why my code became grey, but it is line 3 where I have the comment: "changed Activate() to Select()"

Comment: Thanks I didn't look properly! +1